# How to make the left drawable stick to the text

Tags: android

**XML Code:**

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/shareProduct"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_dark_blue_border_light_blue_solid"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_fb"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:text="Facebook"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

**What I get:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

I thought by giving `gravity="center"` even the drawable comes in the center.

Answer (score 1):

reduce the drawable padding to much lesser  `android:drawablePadding="1dp"` or use the `android:padding="1dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this alternative solution, try to use the padding unless you can:

```
<Button
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_btn_icon"
 android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
```

Comment: This way I get the text to the left. I want the button to be 200dp in width and have text in center.

Comment: Ok, for the 200dp you can change the fill_parent and wrap_content with the desired dimension. Try with gravity="center" and use the android:drawablePadding="-30dip" then adjust the 30dip to find the dimension that fit your desired skin. This is a trick, maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" 
        android:text="Facebook"/>
```

Output:

[image]

For multiple screen support you can use **dimension**(to adjust `paddingLeft`), so that look and feel will same across all the density devices.

Hope this help you.